# Which file path and line number to show in log?

Tags: php

I have written a [logging library](https://github.com/codealchemy/Log) that will add entries to a file or output stream.

When the entry is added to the log, it also includes context information such as the file and line number of the call that was made to add the entry.

My question is: Should I use the file path and line number of the call that added the entry, or the caller that triggered the event to log the message?

## trigger.php:

```
<?php

    $do->something(); #line 2
```

## do.php

```
<?php

    class Do
    {
        public function something ()
        {
            $this->log->add('Did something.', E_USER_NOTICE); # line 6
        }
    }
```

Right now, the message "Did something." is logged as having come from do.php line 6.  Is it better to change the logging class to say that the message came from trigger.php line 2?

**EDIT**

Clarifying a few things.

1. The library includes the whole call stack in the log entry.  So in more feature rich logging classes, you can see a lot more than what the example above entails.
2. The library does make use of logging levels and will filter out levels that aren't needed.  The example above does not show that, but you can look at the library itself to know for sure.

Unfortunately I wasn't clear on how the message is being represented in this one scenario.  This very minor scenario will only show one file path and one line.  **Assuming this could not be changed**, which file path and line number would be logged?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Will line 6 give you sufficient information? if it only says line 6 how do you know where it is called from?? if you use the Do class in multiple different places and it always says line 6 that doesn't seem very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Also, what if you have three level instead of two ? What if you have four ? I recommend you to go with the conventional practice of keeping trace of the line where the actual log() call appears.

```
class client
{
  public function get_some_data()
  {
    $data = $this->get_my_data();

    if (empty($data)) {
      $this->log->add('no data in sight');
    }

    // lots of processing

    if ($something) {
      $this->log->add('data was corrupted');
    }
  }
}

//...

$client->get_some_data();
```

If you only log the upper level call, you would only know that it happened in get_some_data() but not where exactly. You might think "Yes but I can find it using the exact error that was logged", but when you are digging logs to pinpoint a problem that is really not what you want to be doing.

If you have several call to this function and you want more informations about which one logged the line, what you can do is store a minimal stack trace alongside your log, see [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). It can be as minimal as

```
2011-12-25 17:02:37 ERROR "data was corrupted" at /path/client.php:6 (called from /path/somefile.php:57)
```

I would also strongly recommend that you add different logging level, because the logging you want in dev/debug situation is not the one you want in production.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified a few things in my question.  What I'm taking away from this is that I should include both in this example?